# Search button without creating new file C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, button, filepath, savefiledialog

I want to open a dialog to search for a filepath, without already creating the File and only saving the pathfile in a textBox.

This is what I already got, but it creates a new file:

```
System::IO::Stream^ myStream;   
    SaveFileDialog^ saveFileDialog1 = gcnew SaveFileDialog;
    saveFileDialog1->Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
    saveFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 2;
    saveFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;
    if ( saveFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == ::DialogResult::OK )      
    {
        if ( (myStream = saveFileDialog1->OpenFile()) != nullptr )
        {
            textBox->Text = saveFileDialog1->FileName;                  
            myStream->Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling OpenFile is what's creating the file.  Don't do it.

```
System::IO::Stream^ myStream;   
SaveFileDialog^ saveFileDialog1 = gcnew SaveFileDialog;
saveFileDialog1->Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
saveFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 2;
saveFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;
if ( saveFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == ::DialogResult::OK )      
{
    textBox->Text = saveFileDialog1->FileName;                  
}
```

Comment: Now I see the answer I feel stupid, but thanks a lot!
 I addet this line :
saveFileDialog1->OverwritePrompt = false;
because I want to handle the problems later.